# Why does this slice of the arguments parameter disappear when being returned?

Tags: javascript

The line I'm confused about:

```
>            return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP
>                  ? this
>                  : oThis,
>                  aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
```

In the polyfill for bind on the [mdn site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) I think I found a bug, but it might be covered up by a security feature to prevent the arguments array from being leaked. The ternary operator below incorrectly concatenates the function arguments with the supplied this and then the function arguments again and passes that to the function. However within the function the only arguments that show up are the correct values. Where did they go when the function is called.  Calling the function with test code 1,2,3 proves that oThis is used as this and 1,2,3 rather than 1,2,3,1,2,3 is printed out. Why?

Also, why doesn't the comma operator skip over `oThis` and evaluate to just the parameter term. I would think it jumps over oThis because of the comma operator, and evaluates as the arguments from 2nd to last concatenated to all arguments.

```js
if (!Function.prototype.bind2) {
      Function.prototype.bind2 = function(oThis) {
        if (typeof this !== 'function') {
          // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5
          // internal IsCallable function
          throw new TypeError('Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable');
        }
    
        var aArgs   = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),
            fToBind = this,
            fNOP    = function() {},
            fBound  = function() {
              return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP
                     ? this
                     : oThis,
                     aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
            };
        console.log("is the ternary returned?"+ !(this instanceof fNOP));
    console.log("aArgs: " + aArgs + " slice: " + 
    `${aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))}`); 
    //true, aArgs: 1,2,3 slice: 1,2,3,[object Object],1,2,3
        if (this.prototype) {
          // Function.prototype doesn't have a prototype property
          fNOP.prototype = this.prototype; 
        }
        fBound.prototype = new fNOP();
    
        return fBound;
      };
    }
    //Test outputs: this!=global: true args: 1,2,3
    (function(){console.log(`this!=global: ${this!=self} args: 
    ${Array.from(arguments)}`);}.bind2({t:"s"},1,2,3))();
```

Comment: What are you expecting this code to output? You're calling `bind` with `{t:"s"}` as the "this" argument, so of course it doesn't equal `global`.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I'm still not explaining the question. That's to prove to myself that the function oThis wasn't skipped by the comma. I'm confused about the 1,2,3,1,2,3 applied to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The ternary operator below incorrectly concatenates the function arguments with the supplied this and then the function arguments again

No. The ternary has nothing to do with the concatenation.

> Why doesn't the comma operator skip over oThis and evaluate to just the parameter term.

There is no comma operator. There's a comma to separate the two arguments that are passed to the `apply` invocation. The ternary expression is the first argument, the array concatenation is the second argument.

```
fToBind.apply(
  this instanceof fNOP ? this : oThis
,
  aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))
);
```

> You can delete the concat and it still works

No. Try an example that actually passes arguments to the bound function:

```
(function() {
    console.log(`this: ${this}, args: ${Array.from(arguments)}`);
}).bind2("thisValue", 1,2,3)(4,5,6);
```

> I'm confused about the output of `console.log("slice: "+…)`. Where did the extra tacked on arguments go?

That's because you did put the `console.log` in the wrong place. It's not inside the `fBound` function, so the `arguments` object you're seeing there are those of the `.bind2` call.

Comment: Ok, ignore the comma part of the question. I should have put test code into the question to show that before the function is called, there is othis, "1,2,3,othis,1,2,3" being passed outside. You can delete the concat and it still works but why?

Comment: @user5389726598465 What?

Comment: You realize that one can also do partial application with bind? E.g. `Math.max.bind(Math, 1)(2, 3, 4)`. The concat part concats `[1]` and `[2,3,4]`

Comment: @Bergi, I'm not doing a good job of communicating the question, see the output above. I'm confused about the 1,2,3,obj, 1,2,3. Where did the extra tacked on arguments go?

Comment: @Bergi Nowww I get it.